# delete user from group in fedora from command line

Tags: fedora, group

I have been using ubuntu extensively and use the following from the command line:

```
deluser <username> <groupname>
```

It doesn't seem to work in fedora. Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://wiki.polyformal.de/linux/rosetta_stone

The corresponding line translates:

```
Action                 | Debian                | Red Hat/CentOS/Fedora | OpenSUSE               | Gentoo 
-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+----------------------
delete user from group | deluser user group    | gpasswd -d user group | groupmod -R user group | gpasswd -d user group 
                       | gpasswd -d user group |
```

If you know an English Rosetta stone for this kind of task, please tell me. ;)

If you are unsure what exactly a command is doing, the corresponding man page should give you all needed details.

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora, while `gpasswd` solution works, here are some alternative ways that based on `usermod`.

Remove user `myusername` from group `wheel`:

```bash
# Way1: Use --remove Option
usermod --groups wheel --remove myusername

# Way2: Explicitly Specify All Expected Groups
usermod --groups myusername myusername
```

And then you need to **log out** the current user and log in again to see the effect, if no effect, try **reboot** the system.